# How to register SEND intent only for local gallery (images locally on my phone)?

Tags: android

I register my activity for 'sharing' in gallery. By doing this:
My question is I only want to support gallery for images locally on the phone, not the online gallery which is remote like the picasa.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Thank you.

I have added

```
         <data android:scheme="file"/>
          <data android:scheme="content" />
```

to my above intent. But i can' send to my activity regardless it is a local photo or a photo on an online gallery (pisaca).

Answer (score 0):

I believe (not tested) that setting  should do the trick - see the [intent-filter data element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#scheme) docs